# How do you add text gradient using css?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="firstname">
<a href="index.html"><p class="names">DANIEL</p></a>
</div>
```

The above is the html.

```
h1.method1 {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #878787, #000);
background: linear-gradient(top, #878787, #000);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;}

h1.method2 {
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1));
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1));}
```

The above is what i tried to do using .names selector,  and the .firstname .names selector, and i tried a.names selector, I am not sure if the method doesnt work or i am using the wrong selector. But overall i just want to have the text to have a little bit of gradient to look good.

Comment: Yea, wrong selector. This is probably what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/ZdvY9/

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks for the quick feedback, your method works fine, but i think my link attribute may have inherited too many attributes and its not working..what do you think is the best way to fix it. The reason i wanted to add a class to P or an ID to p, is so i can directly point to it and change it, because my link "a" attribute have many modifiers before this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the text-shadow css property with inset at the end of the rule. This is the most cross browser way to do it. IE9 may not support it but that's it.

Use rgba color for greater control and edit the alpha channel in your browser (like firebug)

Answer (score 0):

*source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/*

This is WebKit only, but is the cleanest way to accomplish it as the text remains editable and selectable web text.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, do you know what the background-clip text does? and what the transparent does?

Comment: The `background-clip` property is used to determine whether the backgrounds extends into the border or not. The default is `border-box`, which means it DOES extend into it, but if you set it to `padding-box`, it doesn’t. if you use `content-box` the background only extends to the content area. This value has been removed from the latest development version of the spec.

source: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/